# AngularJS date picker years and months only

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

I am trying to configure the angular ui date picker to just choose years and month and not to show the days but i couldn't do that. is any solutions can i do to achieve this.
thats my plnkr

http://plnkr.co/edit/JR2EuU?p=preview

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
var DatepickerDemoCtrl = function ($scope) {
  $scope.today = function() {
    $scope.dt = new Date();
  };
  $scope.today();

  $scope.showWeeks = false;


  $scope.open = function($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();

    $scope.opened = true;
  };

  $scope.dateOptions = {
    'year-format': "'yy'",
    'starting-day': 1,
    'datepicker-mode':"'month'",
    'min-mode':"month"
  };

};
```

and thats my view

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="MM/yyyy" ng-model="dt" is-open="opened" datepicker-options="{minMode: 'month'}" datepicker-mode="'month'" show-button-bar="false" show-weeks="false" close-on-date-selection="true" />
          <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
```

i found this solution here but i don't want to use Jquery i am looking to use angular js.
http://plnkr.co/edit/JUSAaQoFtU8Kw1KyvXwN?p=preview

Comment: first of all the version of the ui-bootstrap is very old, try update and check its homepage, also i would recomend this one http://indrimuska.github.io/angular-moment-picker/ this handle more native the years.

Answer (score 0):

In your plunker, when I upgraded angular-ui from 0.10 to 0.12 it worked.  Replace line 5 in your index.html with

`<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.js"></script>`

I couldn't find documentation on version 0.10.  The furthest the docs back is [0.12](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/versioned-docs/0.12.0/#timepicker).

Answer (score 0):

i used indrimuska.github.io/angular-moment-picker  and it is really working well and so much modern and easy to configure.